# Get lines from a file with a specific pattern in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file

I have this file:

```
this is line 1 192.168.1.1
this is line 2 192.168.1.2
this is line 3 192.168.1.2
this is line 4 192.168.1.1
this is line 5 192.168.1.2
```

I would like to get, in a bash script, all lines (with tabs) which contains, for example, the pattern "192.168.1.1". By this way, I would get:

```
this is line 1 192.168.1.1
this is line 4 192.168.1.1
```

But i don't want this result:

```
this is line 1 192.168.1.1 this is line 4 192.168.1.1
```

I tried it with sed without success:

```
var='192.168.1.1'
body=`sed -n -e '/$var/p' $file`
echo $body
```

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: What does "without success" mean? Are you aware of the fact that variables are not expanded in single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v var='192.168.1.1' '$NF==var' file

this is line 1 192.168.1.1
this is line 4 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `sed` may help you on same.

```
var="your_ip"
sed -n "/$var/p"  Input_file
```

Or in `awk` following will help on same.

```
var="your_ip"
awk -v var="$var" 'var==$NF'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `grep` command could do that:

```
grep 192.168.1.1 filename
```

Or a more "complex" `grep` command could do that and write it to another file:

```
grep 192.168.1.1 filename > new_filename
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data format is well defined like you said:

```
"this is line <seq> <ip>"
```

you could do simply this:

```
cat file | egrep "192.168.0.1$"
```